# What is this fungus that is growing on my plant, and is it dangerous?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, mycology

This **fungus** is growing on a plant in my front yard and I do not know if it is dangerous for my health or for the plants health. Can you please identify it? I live in Dominican Republic, a tropical island in the Caribbean Sea.

Here are some photos from my yard:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is probably not good for the plant by the looks of it. But I think this question should be moved to gardening.se

Comment: Looks more like an insect invasion...

Comment: Also, please add your location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer won't apply if your plant isn't a cycad (a species from the genus *Cycas*) as only cycads are affected. Cycad aren't native to the Dominican Republic but have been planted as ornamentals in many parts of the world. ***If*** your plant's a cycad, I'm convinced that what your plant has is **NOT** a fungal but insect infection - something far more serious for your plant *but* not harmful for you or other people.

Please compare photos provided to make sure of identification. Even enlarging your top photo,  it's not quite focused or clear enough to be sure. It appears that your white 'fungus' is actually *Aulacaspis yasumatsui* or the Asian cycad scale insect. Athough native to southeast Asia, it's been spreading to many places where cycad are found. Whether it's reached the Dominican Republic yet, I don't know but its been in Florida since the mid-1990s and is found in a number of Caribbean countries. It's now a very serious pest of cycad worldwide, resulting in the death of many.

Here are some photos for you to compare. I did my best to find photos that show greater detail for you to check. If the photos fit what you have, you need to treat your plant to prevent it dying and for the infestation spreading to other cycad on the island. I've no experience with this but the information on how to deal with this pest comes from Central Florida Palm & Cycad Society so they should know the best way to treat this.

[Treatment of Asian Scale](http://www.cfpacs.org/treatment-asian-scale/)

[image: close-up view of Aulacaspis yasumatsui]
 <sup>Image from [Forestry Images](https://www.forestryimages.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=5194062) courtesy of Jeffrey W. Lotz</sup>

[image]
 <sup>Image from [Central Florida Palm & Cycad Society](http://www.cfpacs.org/treatment-asian-scale/)</sup>

Comment: Jude as your answer indicate the photos have not been taken you you, in that case the source of the pictures needs to be mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: Will do. It's weird but when I answer using my phone, either from Chrome or the SE app, most images from a URL won't load. So I end up downloading the images and posting them that way. Using my tablet, images load fine but I don't always have the tablet charged.